# Tailwind CSS 3.0 Disable JIT Mode

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I Understand that the Tailwind CSS uses a new [JIT](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-to-the-jit-engine) engine by default from version 3 onwards.
AS JIT generates the CSS classes on demand, the text editors/IDE fails to show CSS class suggestions via IntelliSense.

Also, it will be an added advantage for developers during the development process without purging the CSS every time. As Tailwind CDN doesn't support third-party tailwind plugins (E.g tailwind-scrollbar) developers cannot rely on it.

1. Is there a way to disable the JIT mode
2. Is there any workaround to overcome the IntelliSense issue?

Comment: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6256#discussioncomment-1747715

Comment: Which editor are you using? VSCode with the "Tailwind CSS Intellisense" plugin shows suggestions for me after upgrading to version 3.x, just like it did with 2.x.

Comment: @EdLucas I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I think VS loads the suggestions from the CSS file linked with the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, in v3.0 the Just-in-Time (JIT) mode is enabled by default and there's no built-in way to disable it. The JIT mode is a key part of Tailwind CSS v3.0's design and functionality, which provides significant improvements to build times and enables all variants out of the box. However, if you still want to disable it, there are a couple of workarounds mentioned in the previous discussion shown by @Rim:

1- Revert to Tailwind CSS v2.x and sacrificing the new features and improvements of v3.

2- Use pattern safelisting in your Tailwind CSS configuration. This is a bit of a hack and might not work as expected in all cases:

```js
   // tailwind.config.js
   module.exports = {
     content: [
       // paths to your files
     ],
     safelist: [
       // array of regexes or strings representing CSS classes
     ],
     // rest of the config
   }
```

3- One other possible workaround is to use CDN, by using the TailwindCSS CDN effectively bypasses the JIT compilation process.

Please note that these workarounds might not be perfect and could lead to other possible issues.